# $F : H_0^1 (\Omega,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^2 (\Omega, \mathbb{R}), \ u \mapsto u^\gamma$ locally Lipschitz-continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I am currently trying to establish the local Lipschitz continuity of the mapping
$$ F : H_0^1 (\Omega,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^2 (\Omega, \mathbb{R}), \ u \mapsto u^\gamma,
$$
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is assumed to be a bounded domain with nice boundary and $\gamma > 1$. In the crucial case $d >2$ welldefinedness is given for $ \gamma \leq \frac{d}{d-2}$.

I was hoping for an estimate of the type "$ \Vert w \Vert_{L^q} \Vert u-v \Vert_{L^p}$" with $w \in H_0^1 (\Omega, \mathbb{R})$ and $q$, $p$ suitable for the application of the Sobolev embeddings. I tried to play with the Mean Value Theorem applied to $F$ pointwise, but in this case I end up with a function $w(\theta, x)$ on $[0,1] \times \Omega$, where $\theta$ depends on the spatial variable $x$. I failed in proving that this mapping is in $H_0^1 (\Omega, \mathbb{R})$.

Do you have easier alternatives how to get started with the estimate? Any help would be appreciated!

Best regards :)

Comment: what about writing $v^\gamma - u^\gamma = \int_0^1 \gamma (u + s(v-u))^{\gamma-1} ds (v-u)$? (ie fundamental theorem). and then crudely estimating the s-integral?

Comment: that is, try to investigate Lipschitz continuity of $t \mapsto t^\gamma$ on $\mathbb R$ first

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I am sure that $t \mapsto t^\gamma$ is locally Lipschitz due to $$\vert t_1^\gamma -  t_2^\gamma \vert \leq \gamma \vert \xi^{\gamma -1} \vert \ \vert t_1 -t_2 \vert$$ by MVT  for suitable $\xi \in [t_1, t_2]$.

Comment: Sorry for not getting the idea behind your hint earlier! Nice one :)

Answer (score 2):

Following the Hint that daw gave you, by the first order expansion of $u\mapsto u^\gamma$ you get
$$
u^\gamma-v^\gamma = (u-v) \,\gamma\int_0^1 \left((1-t)\,u+t\,v\right)^{\gamma-1}\,\mathrm d t
$$
therefore by Hölder's and Minkowski's inequalities, for $(p,q)\in [2,\infty]^2$ such that $1/p + 1/q = 1/2$,
$$
\|u^\gamma-v^\gamma\|_{L^2} \leq \gamma\,\|u-v\|_{L^p} \int_0^1 \|(1-t)\,u+t\,v\|_{L^{q(\gamma-1)}}^{\gamma-1}\,\mathrm d t
\\
\leq \gamma\,\|u-v\|_{L^p} \int_0^1 \left((1-t)\,\|u\|_{L^{q(\gamma-1)}} + t\,\|v\|_{L^{q(\gamma-1)}}\right)^{\gamma-1}\,\mathrm d t
$$
and so since $\gamma-1 > 0$, using the fact that $(a+b)^{\gamma-1} \leq 2^{(\gamma-2)_+} (a^{\gamma-1}+b^{\gamma-1})$, you get
$$
\|u^\gamma-v^\gamma\|_{L^2} \leq \gamma\,\|u-v\|_{L^p} \int_0^1 \|(1-t)\,u+t\,v\|_{L^{q(\gamma-1)}}^{\gamma-1}\,\mathrm d t
\\
\leq \gamma\,2^{(\gamma-2)_+-1}\,\|u-v\|_{L^p}  \left(\|u\|_{L^{q(\gamma-1)}}^{\gamma-1} + \|v\|_{L^{q(\gamma-1)}}^{\gamma-1}\right)
$$
Now you just want to use Sobolev's inequalities to find $p$ and $q$ so that both these norms are controlled by the $H^1$ norm. Since the domain is bounded, if If $d\leq 2$, then the $H^1$ norm controls all $L^p$ norms with $p<\infty$, so it is always true in this case. If $d>2$, then it is sufficient to find them such that $p\leq \frac{2d}{d-2}$ and $q\,(\gamma-1)\leq \frac{2d}{d-2}$. Taking for instance $p=\frac{2d}{d-2}$, then this works as soon as
$$
\gamma -1 \leq \frac{2d}{d-2}\, \frac{1}{q} = \frac{2d}{d-2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{p}\right) = \frac{d}{d-2}-1.
$$

To conclude: As soon as $d\leq 2$ or $\gamma \leq \frac{d}{d-2}$, then
$$
\|u^\gamma-v^\gamma\|_{L^2} \leq \frac{\gamma\,2^{(\gamma-2)_+}}{2}\,\|u-v\|_{H^1} \left(\|u\|_{H^1}^{\gamma-1} + \|v\|_{H^1}^{\gamma-1}\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer, it leaves no questions open!

Comment: Just one litte thing: I think that the fact $(a+b)^{\gamma -1} \leq 2^{(\gamma -2)} (a^{\gamma -1} +b^{\gamma -1})$ relies on convexity of $t \mapsto t^{\gamma -1}$. In case $\gamma \in (1,2)$ we can estimate by $(\max (a,b) )^{\gamma -1}$ to be on the safe side.

Comment: Here $a_+=a$ if it is positive and is $0$ if $a$ is negative. So convexity give you the inequality when $\gamma>2$, but when $\gamma\in[1,2]$, then the inequality is still true with constant $1$. For example $\sqrt{a+b}\leq \sqrt a +\sqrt b$